# TypeError: render() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python

for sprite in sprites:
sprite.render(pen, camera.x, camera.y)

```
    game.render_border(pen, camera.x, camera.y)
```

i need some some help I'm fairly new with sprites

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This typically indicates that you did not add the `self` argument in the instance methods signature. If `game` is an instance of a class `Game`, and `Game` has an instance method `render_border(pen, x, y)`, then you can resolve this error by adding the `self` variable.

```py
class Game:
    def render_border(self, pen, x, y):
        # render the border...
```